# Obtain Adobe Marketing Cloud ID when Cookies not set previously using DTM?

Tags: javascript, dynamic, adobe, adobe-analytics

I'm trying to figure out how to capture the Adobe Marketing Cloud ID (MID) when a page first loads using a Data Element (or by whatever alternative method will work). My Data Element logic works fine, if the Marketing Cloud cookie already exists. If there is no Marketing Cloud Cookie already existing, my data element reads the Marketing Cloud ID cookie as it is being written but the MID is not populated in the cookie at the time the Data Element reads it.

Is there any way I can access the value and report it in an eVar on the initial page load? I actually take the MID and combine it with an additional value to create the eVar value. As stated my code works unless the Marketing Cloud ID doesn't exist and has to be created during the page load.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Visitor.getInstance()`](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/mcvid/mcvid_getinstance.html) to get the `Visitor` instance, and then and then [`Visitor.getMarketingCloudVisitorID()`](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/mcvid/mcvid-getmcvid.html) to get the MC ID (what you see in the `mid=` param)

**example:**

```
var visitor = Visitor.getInstance("[mcorgid]@AdobeOrg")
s.eVar1 = visitor.getMarketingCloudVisitorID(); // set v2 with mid= value
```

If you implemented the MC ID service as a DTM tool, you can alternatively use `_satellite.getVisitorId()` instead of `Visitor.getInstance()`, e.g.:

```
s.eVar1 = _satellite.getVisitorId().getMarketingCloudVisitorID();
```

So for your **Data Element**, instead of doing a Cookie type (I assume that's what you did), you will need to use Custom Script type and return the value, e.g.

```
try {
  return _satellite.getVisitorId().getMarketingCloudVisitorID();
} catch(e) {console.log(e);}
```

**(Update) Alternatives**

From your comment below (my bold for emphasis):

> Just to be clear, this only happens to me on the first page when the
>   Marketing Cloud cookies don't exist. **I do see the MID in the server
>   call.**

Since you have confirmed that AA is getting an `mid=` value in its request, instead of trying to push the actual value of it to your eVar, you can pop it indirectly in other ways.

**Dynamic Variables**

[dynamic variable](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/implement/dynvars_overview.html) syntax to reference the `mid=` param:

```
s.eVar1 = "D=mid";
```

**Note:** `D=` is the default [dynamic variable prefix](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/implement/dynamicVariablePrefix.html) syntax. Check your AA tool config/other custom code to ensure it is not being set to something else.

**Processing Rules**

If you have access to create processing rules, you can setup a processing rule to set your eVar to `mid=` value there.

Comment: -so are you saying that this info will be available to the Data Element even if the Markting Cloud ID Cookie doesn't have the MID available yet? Thanks.

Comment: I tried the above approach but I have the same issue. No value is returned by _satellite.getVisitorId().getMarketingCloudVisitorID(); if I hit a page and my cookies have been cleared. I'm assuming it is a timing issue where the MID is not generated yet?

Comment: @MichaelJohns So to be clear, you implemented the MC ID service as a DTM *tool*, right?

Comment: Yes, it is implemented as a tool within DTM

Comment: @MichaelJohns hmm okay.. I have tested it on my sandbox and it pops for me, and have seen no issues with timing. But if you are certain everything is otherwise setup correctly and you've done the above correctly, let's try and confirm/deny timing vs. something else.  Firstly, do you see the `mid=` value in the AA request? if so, then this makes me believe perhaps you didn't actually do the above correctly, or there is something else going on.

Comment: Also, clear your cookies and go to a page and let the page load fully and then put `_satellite.getVisitorId().getMarketingCloudVisitorID();` into the js console. Do you get a value?

Comment: Just to be clear, this only happens to me on the first page when the Marketing Cloud cookies don't exist. I do see the MID in the server call. If I look at the cookie contents under the initial condition, when the data element executes, it only has a little bit of data in it (e.g "-179204249"). If I look at the cookie contents after that, on same page load,  it has the full encoded string with MID in the cookie.

Comment: Okay based on your comment, I personally still think there's some kind of disconnect in your code. A typo somewhere, Bad set/get/ref logic. That sort of thing. But since you did confirm one thing, I've added some solutions that should work as an alternative, if you want to abandon pursuit and call it a day.

Comment: thank you for your solutions you updated but I can't do any post-processing as you suggest because the eVar value is grabbed on one main  page and sent to a 3rd-party so it has to be actual value. Otherwise that would work. Sorry I didn't disclose this initially.

Comment: Adobe Support is telling me to try: var analyticsID = visitor.getAnalyticsVisitorID(callback)

Comment: @MichaelJohns Well Adobe Support is wrong. [getAnalyticsVisitorID](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/mcvid/mcvid_getanalyticsvisitorid.html) returns the legacy Analytics Id, if available/applicable. Which is NOT the mid value